# Dataflow ReadFromMongoDB fails with dependency error

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have written pyton code which reads data from mongodb collection and writes it to gcs bucket.

My dataflow pipeline is as below:

```
    p 
    | ReadFromMongoDB(uri='mongodb+srv://mongo_url',db='db_name',coll='column_name',bucket_auto=True) 
    | "WriteMyFile" >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://bucket_name/file123.json')         
    p.run()
```

My dataflow pipeline fails with below error:

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs
```

As per [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#sdk-for-java) document, pymongo (which is required dependency to solve dnspython issue) is already installed in dataflow workers. What else needed to be done?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because dataflow worker only installs basic requirements of pymongo. And dnspython is included in pymongo extra dependencies so you'll have to use pymongo[srv] as a dependency to resolve dnspython module. You can try to include pymongo[srv]== in you requirements.txt and then submit the pipeline with `--requirements_file` flag, it will make dataflow worker install the required python dependencies when the container is launched.